# How can I reload the contents of iframe on Windows Metro Style App

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to have "reload" button and make the contents of iframe reloaded when clicked on Windows Metro Style App.
When I clicked the button, Javascript runtime error occurs and it says that there is no write access.

Source code is as follows:

== default.html ==

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://example.com" width="800px" height="400px"></iframe>
<button id="reloadButton">Reload</button>
```

== default.js ==

```
var reloadButton = document.getElementById("reloadButton");
reloadButton.addEventListener("click", reload, false);

function reload() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
    iframe.contentWindow.location.reload();
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

You should write something like:

```
iframe.contentWindow.location.href = "http://www.example.com"`
```

For updating the URL of the page inside a frame you can, for example, [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) it to the parent of the frame - if you have access to the source code of the page

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Using postMessage, I could refresh the page in iframe from the button on the parent window. I put the sample code on Gist: https://gist.github.com/3792928